# Noise removal using adaptive noise cancellation algorithms in real time systems

Tags: audio, noise-cancellation

I am newbie in signal processing. I want to remove noise from real time audio signal using adaptive noise cancellation(LMS&RLS) algorithms. I don't know how to choose reference signal(noise signal) for the algorithm from the incoming noise corrupted signal.  So can anyone help me to select the noise signal for the reference of ANC algorithms?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In real time application adaptive noise cancellation uses single sensor for signal reception.The single sensor consist of a  delay  z-Δ to produce a delayed version of incoming signal d(n), denoted by x(n), which de-correlates the noise while leaving the target signal component correlated. So here not needed reference signal separately but delay creates uncorrelated noise from the incoming noise corrupted signal.[image]