# LMS adaptive filter noise suppression- question about my implementation

Tags: python, lms

I am writing LMS filter to suppress noise in wav file (I know there are many modules to do this but I need to write LMS manually now as I will translate it into C later).

According to this answer[1], the inputs will be the noisy voice and a shifted version of it
here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

#Reading wav
fs, data = wavfile.read('te.wav')
#d= vector of first channel samples
d = np.transpose(data)[0]
print(data.shape)
#delay= 2 seconds
xd= np.roll(d,2*fs)

M=5
L=d.size
w=np.zeros(M)
y=np.zeros(L-M)
e=np.zeros(L-M)
meu=0.1

for i in range(0,L-M):
    xPart=xd[i:i+M]
    #print(xPart.shape)
    y[i]=xPart.dot(w)
    e[i]=d[i]-y[i]
    w = w+ meu*e[i]*xPart

print(w)
```

now, the final value if filter is [nan,nan,...,nan] and a lot of overflows happens.

I don't know what is wrong.

- is this implementation right?

[1] [Noise removal using adaptive noise cancellation algorithms in real time systems](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/48681/noise-removal-using-adaptive-noise-cancellation-algorithms-in-real-time-systems)

Comment: I see good reason to implement things yourself; but there's a lot of signal processing libraries for C, so C shouldn't be the reason you've got to do this in python first (makes so little sense).

Comment: I have to do it totally without using any external library even in C. So, I work first in python close to what I will do in C

Comment: I'm all for you doing it in Python to understand how the *algorithm* works. I'm just telling you that Python is not a good practice ground to learn how to write C.

Comment: You might be running into stability issues. make sure 0 < mu < 2/max(y(t)^2), where y(t) is your received signal

Comment: Marcus Müller u r right

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 I tried a very low value (0.0000001), this made overflows ans "nan"s disappear, but the output raw data is just a noise :D

Comment: you might need to take the conjugate of w first

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 why ? the data is voice samples so no difference